# How to use props value in non component class which imported in component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-props

I would like to access `this.props.apiendpoint` in `api.js` which imported in `test.js` which is component base class.

```
# api.js
import axios from 'axios';
export function fetchData(){
   return axios.post(apiendpoint);
}
```

```
# App.js
import test from test.js
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.apiendpoint = 'api.example.com';
  }
   
  render() {
    <test apiendpoint = {apiendpoint} />
  }
}
```

```
# test.js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {fetchData}  from api.js;

const test = ({
}) => {
   console.log(this.props.apiendpoint); // this value how to acccess in api.js 
   fetchData();
}
test.propTypes = {
apiendpoint: PropTypes.String,
}
test..defaultProps = {
apiendpoint : null,
}
```

like `fetchData()` I have many functions for API related passing `apiendpoint` for each function not good practice.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why not pass as an argument to the function?

Comment: means `fetchData(this.props.apiendpoint)` ? like fetchData I have many functions for API related passing apiendpoint for each function not good practice

Comment: How should I know if you have many other functions that you want to use the `this.props.apiendpoint`? It is not included in the question. Your use-case seems like a design mistake tbh, why do you need a prop of a component in a file where you export actions?

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: AFAIU, you create an endpoint string inside a component constructor, and pass it to another component which should pass it to an external file with actions. My best bet is setting axios default baseUrl like `axios.defaults.baseUrl = this.props.apiendpoint`

Comment: This approach is working. Thanks @SinanYaman but need to extra thing like using interceptor I have to append value `if (!req.url.includes(req.baseUrl)) {
          req.url = `${req.baseUrl}${req.url}`;
        }`

Answer (score 2):

I would add apiEndPoint as an argument to fetchData function.

```
# api.js
import axios from 'axios';
export function fetchData(apiendpoint){
   return axios.post(apiendpoint);
}
```

And then call it from test.js by passing prop as a parameter.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {fetchData}  from api.js;

const test = ({
}) => {
   console.log(fetchData(this.props.apiendpoint));

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but this is not fit my questions.